# Box corner points from position, orientation and scale

Tags: matlab, rotation, computer-vision, ros

I have a three dimensional bounding box represented by a position, a scale and an orientation as quaternion (for those familiar with it, it is a ROS cube marker). The position should be the centroid of the box, the scale is the size along its three axes and the orientation is w.r.t the world coordinate system. What I want to do now is to calculate the 8 corner points from a box represented as described above. Unfortunately, the below code "fails slightly" (i.e. the result looks close to correct, but is not entirely).

```
%% first, compute the bounding box without rotation
centroid(1) = boundingBox.Pose.Position.X;
centroid(2) = boundingBox.Pose.Position.Y;
centroid(3) = boundingBox.Pose.Position.Z;
length = boundingBox.Scale.X;
width = boundingBox.Scale.Y;
height = boundingBox.Scale.Z;

obb(1,:) = length/2 * [0 1 0] - height/2 * [0 0 1] + width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(2,:) = -length/2 * [0 1 0] - height/2 * [0 0 1]+ width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(3,:) = -length/2 * [0 1 0] + height/2 * [0 0 1] + width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(4,:) = length/2 * [0 1 0] + height/2 * [0 0 1] + width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(5,:) = length/2 * [0 1 0] - height/2 * [0 0 1] - width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(6,:) = -length/2 * [0 1 0] - height/2 * [0 0 1] - width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(7,:) = -length/2 * [0 1 0] + height/2 * [0 0 1] - width/2 * [1 0 0];
obb(8,:) = length/2 * [0 1 0] + height/2 * [0 0 1] - width/2 * [1 0 0];

%% incorporate rotation
quat(1) = boundingBox.Pose.Orientation.W;
quat(2) = boundingBox.Pose.Orientation.X;
quat(3) = boundingBox.Pose.Orientation.Y;
quat(4) = boundingBox.Pose.Orientation.Z;
rotm = quat2rotm(quat);    
obb = (inv(rotm) * obb')';  % why inv?!

%% move to actual position
obb = bsxfun(@plus, obb, centroid);
```

First, I used obb = (rotm * obb')' instead of obb = (inv(rotm) * obb')' but the result was obviously wrong. Empirically, I came up with "inv", which looked much better, but I never understood why. Now I have figured out that it is not really correct anyway...

Any help figuring out my mistake is highly appreciated :)